# Removing items from array and DOM simultaneously

Tags: javascript

I have a large array of items which I am removing one by one within a setInterval.

```
var randomInt = function(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
};

var showItems = function() {
    $.each(items, function(key, val) {
        $('.list').append('<div class="item" id="i'+key+'">'+val+'</div>');
    });
};

var interval = setInterval(function() {
    var id = randomInt(0, items.length);
    items.splice(id, 1);
    $('#i'+id).remove();
    if (items.length < 10) {clearInterval(interval);}
}, 200);
```

The problem arises when the list starts to become shorter. Let's say items starts with 500 entries. Once `items.length` equals 200, the ids within the DOM stay the same. This results in items being deleted from the array while not from the DOM.

Another method I've thought of is `delete items[id]`, but then there's the problem of sparse removal when an item has already been deleted. Once the defined item count reaches ~20, it takes an exceptionally long time for anything more to happen.

The solution I can think of is to redraw the DOM at every delete but that sounds awful and the results (both aesthetic and computational) would be ugly!

Comment: When is `showItems` called?

Comment: The problem is that splicing an element out of an array adjusts the indexes of all the elements after it. So their indexes no longer match the IDs of the corresponding DOM elements. You need to decouple these, by putting the IDs into the array elements explicitly.

Comment: @Barmar I understand what splice does, which is why I chose it over `delete`. I explain exactly what you said within my question. You're saying create a second array with the DOM ids?

Comment: No, I'm saying `items` should be an array of objects `{ id: xxx, value: xxx }`. Then you can do `$("#"+items[i].id).remove()`.

Comment: @Barmar Ah that's an excellent idea. However this array I have no control over so I would have to build my own object to replace it during runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using IDs for your DIVs, do something like this:

```
<div class="list">
  <div class="item">First DIV</div>
  <div class="item">Second DIV</div>
  ...
</div>
```

Instead of `$('#i'+id).remove();` do `$('.list > .item').eq(id).remove();`

Comment: $('.list>div.item') should be just fine

Comment: I edited the code to the improved format @Christophe suggested